# recreating /boot on debian

Tags: debian

I set up a fully encrypted (luks on lvm on softraid-1) debian jessie with a usb-stick holding the /boot partition and lost that stick (yes, kind of funny).

I got back into the system recovery and created another /boot partition on a usb-stick. I changed the UUID in /etc/fstab and mounted it on /boot.

I ran `apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64`, the same with dpkg -i and the cached package in /var/cache/apt/archives, both commands completed successfully but my /boot remains empty.

Any ideas how I could get the kernel-images on /boot? Could I just copy a boot partition from another system and update/install grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinstalling a virtual package.

You need to find what package is required by `linux-image-amd64`, so you will find the real kernel package. Reinstall that package.

You should also reinstall grub and possibly manually do a `update-initramfs` to all targets.

Comment: I installed the specific packages with apt, clarified that in the question, sorry for forgetting that, also ran the grub-install and update-initramfs, the latter completed fine but the first complained, probably due to missing kernel

Comment: ok, manually fetching the depending package and installing that with dpkg solved it, I think I misunderstood your answer. Thanks for the help anyway